# Right way to implement prometheus_client.multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector (Django + Celery)

Tags: prometheus

I have:

1. django app run with `python manage.py runserver`
2. celery worker run with `celery -A project worker -l info`
3. celery beat run with `celery -A project beat -l info`

They will be deployed in their own pods in kubernetes.

`/metrics` endpoint is exposed in Django app but metrics are being gathered in Celery tasks. 
And because these two apps are run in two different process (pods) they have two different registries.

If there is any way to handle this?

It seems that `prometheus_client.multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector` can help.
I tried this but it didn't work:

**settings.py**

```
registry = CollectorRegistry()
multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry, path='/home/aleksandrovalbert/Work/blackbox_exporter/exporter/multiproc-tmp')
```

**views.py**

```
from project.settings import registry

def export(request):
    metrics_page = prometheus_client.generate_latest(registry)
    return HttpResponse(metrics_page, content_type=prometheus_client.CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)
```

**tasks.py**

```
registry = CollectorRegistry()
multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry, path='/home/aleksandrovalbert/Work/blackbox_exporter/exporter/multiproc-tmp')


class TestBeatPeriodicTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(minutes=1)

    metric = Gauge(
       name='test_beat',
       documentation='Task Documentation.',
       registry=registry
    )

    def run(self):
        metric.set(888)
```

Or this can be handled with pushgateway only?

Comment: Any progress on this one, I am facing exactly the same issue?

Comment: @klementomeri, I used https://github.com/belousovalex/prometheus_redis_client as metrics storage